# How does log4NET know the # of line where a log event is fired

Tags: log4net

I am curious how does log4NET can use %L to get the # of line where a log event is fired. Could you give me some elaboration?

Thanks.

Comment: Logging line number http://forums.asp.net/t/1439034.aspx?log4net+failed+to+log+line+number+file+name

Answer (score 3):

It uses a StackTrace as described in [the log4net documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Layout.PatternLayout.html).

Note the caveats in the lognet documentation:

- WARNING Generating caller location information is extremely slow. Its use should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.
- CAUTION
  The System.Diagnostics.StackTrace class has this to say about Release builds:

  "StackTrace information will be most informative with Debug build configurations. By default, Debug builds include debug symbols, while Release builds do not. The debug symbols contain most of the file, method name, line number, and column information used in constructing StackFrame and StackTrace objects. StackTrace might not report as many method calls as expected, due to code transformations that occur during optimization."

  This means that in a Release build the caller information may be incomplete or may not exist at all! Therefore caller location information cannot be relied upon in a Release build.